# writing a document in hebrew and getting Ł after every mathematical formula

Tags: lyx

I don't know if it's the right place to ask in, because I use LyX but if I'm wrong I'd like that you tell me where should I ask.

I use LyX,and installed MikTex + Culmus for supporting hebrew fonts.
When I convert lyx file to PDF file by doing "export", I get the char "Ł" after every mathematical formula. It happens only when the document is in Hebrew.
When I try to write a document in English, it doesn't happen.
I checked in the package manager of MikTex whether the package of babel is installed, and it is installed. So what's the problem here? what should I do?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to TeX.SX.  LyX questions are indeed welcome here, although most of us are not LyX users, so it may take longer to get an answer.  One thing that would help would be to make a small document that shows the problem and post the code to that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there have been problems in Hebrew with this character before, so could it be related to the problem as posed in ["babel \L command reverses letters, inserts Ł symbol"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36982/babel-l-command-reverses-letters-inserts-symbol)? In that case the solution was to use `\def\L{\protect\pL}` as a workaround...